# How to open/import new html files with Python cgi?

Tags: python, cgi

I want to show/display test.html (which is located in the same directory as the script) if the input of the user is correct.

**Test.html:**

```
<html>
<head><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
  <p>Test</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**Form.html:**

```
<form action="submit.cgi" method="get">
<p>Question 1</p>   
<select name="form1">
<option value="1">Test 1</option>
<option value="2">Test 2</option>
</select>

<p>Question 2</p>
<select name="form2">
<option value="3">Test 3</option>
<option value="4">Test 4</option>
</select>
</form>
```

**Python script (submit.cgi):**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi
import cgitb

print ('Content-type: text/html\n\n')
form = cgi.FieldStorage() 
if form["form1"].value == '1' and form["form2"].value == '3':
    ...?
```

I know it's possible to just print the whole test.html in the script (that worked), but i'd prefer to import/open html pages (especially with multiple or large html files). I tried:

```
open("test.html")
```

But that didn't work. Does somebody know how it can be done?

Comment: Use a Python web framework instead of tinkering with CGI

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
if form["form1"].value == '1' and form["form2"].value == '3':
    print ('''
  <head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='test.html'" /></head>    
''')
```

Comment: If you answer to your own question, at least explain how it actually solves the problem you were having...

Comment: Instead of printing each single html line I can now print the whole html page with just the code above. Keeps the CGI clean and it's more efficient.

Comment: the code you wrote above actually does a refresh to a different page. It doesn't print html. You should definitely use a framework instead of CGI.